# Globally catch exceptions thrown from WCF async calls in a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, exception, async-await

I have a WPF application that communicates with a WCF service. I'm currently calling my WCF service from my ViewModels (I'm using the MVVM pattern) using the following `async` based pattern:

```
public async override void MyCommandImplementation()
{
    using (var proxy = new MyProxy())
    {
        var something = await proxy.GetSomethingAsync();
        this.MyProperty = something;
    }
}
```

As I'm following the MVVM pattern, I have `ICommand` public properties that are exposed by my ViewModels, so associated command implementation won't return `Task<T>` objects as they are like event handlers. So the exception handling is actually pretty simple, i.e. I am able to catch any exception thrown from my WCF service using the following pattern:

```
public async override void MyCommandImplementation()
{
    try
    {
        using (var proxy = new MyProxy())
        {
            var something = await proxy.GetSomethingAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (FaultException<MyFaultDetail> ex)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

So far so good, everything work as expected if the server throws an exception that is automatically converted to a SOAP Fault thanks to a custom WCF behavior.

As I have some common exceptions that can be thrown everywhere in my service (for instance each WCF operation can throw a `AuthenticationException` that'll by converted on client side to a `FaultException<AuthenticationFaultDetail>` exception), I've decided to handle some exceptions in a common place in my application, i.e. by handling the `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event. This works just fine, I can catch all my `FaultException<AuthenticationFaultDetail>` exceptions everywhere, display an error message to the user, and prevent the application from exiting:

```
private static void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Exception handler that handles some common exceptions
    // such as FaultException<AuthenticationFaultDetail>
    if (GlobalExceptionHandler.HandleException(e.Exception))
    {
        // Expected exception, so we're fine
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // We're not fine. We couldn't handle the exception
        // so we'll exit the application
        // Log...etc.
    }
}
```

Everything works pretty well because `FaultException` are thrown in the UI thread thanks to the `async` pattern and the synchronization context switch before/after the `await` keyword.

My problem is, other exception can be thrown in another thread than my UI thread, for example in case of `EndPointNotFoundException` thrown at the `await proxy.GetSomethingAsync();` line (case of WCF service shutdown on server side).

Those exceptions won't be handled in the `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException` event handler because they are not thrown in the UI thread. I can handle them in the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event, but I'm not able to do anything else than do some logging and exit the application (there is basically no "e.Handled"-like property).

So my question is: how could I handle exceptions thrown in background threads in case of an async WCF call in one place of my application?

The best I can think of right now is something like the following:

```
public class ExceptionHandler : IDisposable
{
    public void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        // Do something clever here
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do nothing here, I just want the 'using' syntactic sugar
    }
}

...

public async override void MyCommandImplementation()
{
    using (var handler = new ExceptionHandler())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var proxy = new MyProxy())
            {
                var something = await proxy.GetSomethingAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<MyFaultDetail> ex)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // For other exceptions in any thread
            handler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But this would require me to refactor a lot of code (each time I asynchronously call a web service).

Any idea that would allow me to *not* refactor a huge amount of code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I'm not a big fan of centralized/global exception handling. My personal preference would be to either handle the exception everywhere or write your own proxy wrapper object that will handle/translate the expected fault exceptions.

That said, there is an approach you can consider (though it requires modifying all your commands).

First, factor the actual logic into an `async Task` method, as such:

```
public async Task MyCommandAsync()
{
  try
  {
    using (var proxy = new MyProxy())
    {
      var something = await proxy.GetSomethingAsync();
    }
  }
  catch (FaultException<MyFaultDetail> ex)
  {
    // Do something here
  }
}

public async override void MyCommandImplementation()
{
  MyCommandAsync();
}
```

Normally, I recommend implementing `async ICommand`s with an `async Task ExecuteAsync` method and matching `async void Execute` which will just do `await ExecuteAsync();`. The example I have above is almost the same except the `async void` method is *not* `await`ing the `Task`. This is dangerous and I'll explain below.

Keeping your logic in an `async Task` gives you one tremendous advantage: you can unit test much more easily. Also, `async Task` methods have different exception handling which you can (ab)use to solve your problem.

An `async Task` method - if the returned `Task` is never `await`ed - will raise [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx). Note that this will *not* crash your process (as of .NET 4.5); your handler must decide the best response. Since your `async void` method is *not* `await`ing the `Task` returned by your `async Task` method, any exceptions will end up in `UnobservedTaskException`.

So that will work, but it has one serious side effect: *any* unobserved `Task` exception will end up in the same handler (not just ones from your `ICommand`s). The reason that unobserved task exceptions were changed in .NET 4.5 to be ignored by default is because *that situation is no longer unusual* in `async` code. For example, consider this code which will attempt to download from two different urls and take the first response:

```
async Task<string> GetMyStringAsync()
{
  var task1 = httpClient.GetAsync(url1);
  var task2 = httpClient.GetAsync(url2);
  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);
  return await completedTask;
}
```

In this case, if the slower url results in an error, then that exception will be sent to `UnobservedTaskException`.

Comment: 1/2

+1, thanks a lot for this answer, this is very helpful and well explained. I definitely agree with the "async Task MyCommandAsync" / "async override void MyCommandImplementation" pattern because as you said it makes the code much more testable.

The `UnobservedTaskException` event is interesting, but kind of dangerous IMO. Its behavior changed between .Net4 and .Net4.5, and the event will only be raised when the GC does its job.

Comment: 2/2 
So the answer I think is to separate the `ICommand` implementation and the async processing in two methods. One does the async processing and returns a Task. The second one awaits the first and as I need a kind of global exception handling, I could write the logic once and call it using `await MyCommandAsync().ContinueWith(z => MyGlobalExceptionHandler(z.Exception)...);` in the second method.

Comment: Oh, btw, I just discovered you were the author of this [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on MSDN, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently into aspect oriented programming. So I'm using [Postsharps](http://www.postsharp.net/) method interception aspect for service calls. It allows you to centralize the code used for calling services among other things. I also use it for logging and thread synchronization.

**Edit: I just found out that the await keyword is not yet supported. (Coming in 3.1).**

Here is an example:

```
[Serializable]
internal class ServiceCall : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
  public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
  {
    try
    {
        args.Proceed();
    }
    catch (FaultException<DCErrorMessage> f)
    {
        showError(f.Detail.Message + "\r\n" + f.Detail.Callstack, f.Detail.Title);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        showError(e.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

And here is how its used

```
[ServiceCall]
public Something getSomethingAsync()
{
   return await _client.getSomethingAsync();
}
```

Aspects can also be applied to entire classes or assemblies.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this would be a great way to solve the problem if `async` was supported. Other issue is that unfortunately we don't currently use postsharp so it would be a huge change for our solution. +1 anyway