# Unable to catch Webservice call method within try catch block

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, async-await

I am developing a WP8 application. I created a web service on out-systems and then I am calling those web service methods in my app:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient ws = new WebServiceClient();
try
{
 ws.FetchInboxAsync(EmailId);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

Now if the server is down, I expect the control to go into the catch block but it does not and I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user
>   code.

I do realize that the web service call method is asynchronous, so its exception would not be caught in try catch. On forums, people suggest using await keyword. But when I write

> await ws.FetchInboxAsync(EmailId);

I get an error : Cannot await void.

I tried something mentioned in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865523/why-cant-i-catch-an-exception-from-async-code), but still I get the same exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to FetchInboxCompleted event:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient ws = new WebServiceClient();
ws.FetchInboxCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.FetchInboxCompletedEventArgs>(c_FetchInboxCompleted);
ws.FetchInboxAsync(EmailId);
```

And in event handler, check the result:

```
static void c_FetchInboxCompleted(object sender, serviceReference1.FetchInboxCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     // check e.Error which contains the exception, if any
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but before the control can go into the event handler, the same unhandled exception (that I mentioned in the question) stops the execution and crashes the app. What I want is that  I should be able to protect the app from such scenarios and instead pop up some message e.g. server is currently unavailable.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158250/globally-catch-exceptions-thrown-from-wcf-async-calls-in-a-background-thread help?

Answer (score 3):

If the auto-generated WCF client proxy supports it, you should be able to await a method ending with `TaskAsync`:

```
await ws.FetchInboxTaskAsync(EmailId);
```

If the auto-generated WCF client proxy doesn't define this method, then you can define it yourself [as described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap):

```
public static Task FetchInboxTaskAsync(this ServiceReference1.WebServiceClient client, string emailId)
{
  return Task.Factory.FromAsync(client.BeginFetchInbox, client.EndFetchInbox, emailId, null);
}
```